# How to sum one variable group by two variables?? R language

Tags: r, sum

**I have one dataframe:**

```
    Date   area    sales

1     201204   shanghai    23

2     201204 beijing     25

3     201204 beijing     16

4     201205 shanghai    55

5     201205 beijing     17

6     201205 shanghai    16
```

**what I want to output is a table as follows:**

```
Date   shanghai  beijing 

201204  23        41

201205  71        17
```

**How would I do this in R? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Two options, one with base function `aggregate`, the other with plyr's `ddply`. I made up my own data since yours isn't reproducible, but you should be able to get the point:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:3], 100, TRUE),
                  x2 = sample(letters[6:3], 100, TRUE),
                  value = rnorm(100))

aggregate(value ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, FUN = 'sum')

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(x1,x2), summarize, foo = sum(value))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This way maybe much easier and more effective :  code: xtabs(sales ~ Date + area, mydf)